# AWS SES allows to track if mail send or fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want to SES provided by amazon to send mail from my application that is in Java. I read documentation and it says that it will send mail but it doesnot give status of that each and every mail send or failed. It only gives count of mails failed through API method GetSendStatistics. Is there any way that each mail send I will get notification of each and every mail in my Application I need to show status of each main in my application is it possible using SES?

Thanks